# In OneToMany Relationship using @JoinColumn in Child table value get updated instead of insert for saveAll() Method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I Have created OneToMany Relationship between Person And CreditCard, One Person Can Have Many Credit Card,When i'm Adding new Creditcard for person in CreditCard Table Using Person id as foregin key at that time it going to update the existing one instead of making new entry for that Credit card.

I Have Make RelationShip as Follow :
Person Class ::

```
package com.example.model;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "persondb")
public class Person {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Integer id;

     @Column(name = "firstname")
     private String firstName;

     @Column(name = "lastname")
     private String lastName;

     @Column(name = "money")
     private Double money;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")//,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<CreditCard> creditCard;

    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    public Person(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName, Double money, List<CreditCard> creditCard) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.money = money;
        this.creditCard = creditCard;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Double getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    public void setMoney(Double money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

    public List<CreditCard> getCreditCard() {
        return creditCard;
    }

    public void setCreditCard(List<CreditCard> creditCard) {
        this.creditCard = creditCard;
    }



}
```

I Have Created **Two Tables** one is **Person** and another one is **CreditCard**, the person is **Parent table** and **Creditcard is child table**. **CreditCard has foregin key as person_id which has reference of Person class Primary key**.

CreditCard Class ::

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "creditcarddb")
public class CreditCard {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Integer id;

     @Column(name = "type")
     private String type;

     @Column(name = "number")
     private String number;

     @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)//(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name="person_id", nullable=false)
     private Person person;

    public CreditCard() {
        super();
    }

    public CreditCard(Integer id, String type, String number, Person person) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.number = number;
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

I'm Using here **Rest Controller**

PersonController ::

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.model.Person;
import com.example.service.CreditCardService;
import com.example.service.PersonService;

@RestController
//@Controller
public class PersonController {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);

    ModelAndView models = new ModelAndView();

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    private CreditCardService creditCardService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/PersonList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getRecords(Model model) {
        logger.debug("Received request to show records page");
        List<Person> persons = personService.getAll();

        List<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for(Person per : persons) {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setId(per.getId());
            p.setFirstName(per.getFirstName());
            p.setMoney(per.getMoney());
            p.setLastName(per.getLastName());
            p.setCreditCard(creditCardService.getAll(per.getId()));
            person.add(p);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("list","persons",person);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAdd(Model model) {
        logger.debug("Received request to show add page");
        models.setViewName("AddPerson");
        return models;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/personEntry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView postAdd(@ModelAttribute("personAttribute") Person person) {
        logger.debug("Received request to add new record");
        personService.add(person);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/PersonList");
    }   

}
```

Here in CreditCard Controller at a time of adding new CreditCard for person at that time i'm taking the all list of it's existing card first and then by **using saveAll method** i'm going to save existing as well as new CreditCard into DB **But instead Saving the new CreditCard it's going to replace the existing one.** **How i can solve this issue.**

CreditCardController ::

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.model.CreditCard;
import com.example.model.Person;
import com.example.repository.PersonRepository;
import com.example.service.CreditCardService;

@RestController
//@Controller
@RequestMapping(("/main/creditcard"))
public class CreditCardController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreditCardController.class);

    @Autowired
    CreditCardService creditCardService;

    @Autowired
     PersonRepository personRepository;

    ModelAndView models = new ModelAndView();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAdd(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer personId,Model model) {
        logger.debug("Received request to show add page");
        model.addAttribute("creditCardAttribute", new CreditCard());
        model.addAttribute("personId", personId);
        return new ModelAndView("AddCard","personId",personId);
        //return "AddCard";
    }

    //@Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCard", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    //@PostMapping(value = "/addCard")
    public ModelAndView postAdd(@RequestParam("personId") Integer personId,@ModelAttribute("creditCardAttribute") CreditCard creditCard,BindingResult binding) { //@RequestBody  CreditCard creditCard @ModelAttribute("creditCard") CreditCard creditCard
        //@RequestParam("personId") Integer personId
        //@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer personId
        logger.debug("Received request to add new credit card");
        logger.debug("-------------------->-------------------->------------------->");
        logger.debug("Integer Value Received Is" + " " + personId);

        List<CreditCard> cc =  creditCardService.get(personId);
        List<CreditCard> list = new ArrayList<CreditCard>();
        list.addAll(cc);
        Person p = personRepository.findById(personId).get();
        logger.debug("The Value Printed in the Person Object" + " "+p.getId());

        creditCard.setPerson(p);
        cc.add(creditCard);
        list.add(creditCard);
        creditCardService.addAll(list);
        //creditCardService.add(creditCard);
        //return "Success";
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/PersonList");
    }

}
```

PersonService ::

```
package com.example.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.model.Person;
import com.example.repository.CreditCardRepository;
import com.example.repository.PersonRepository;

@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    CreditCardRepository creditCardRepository;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonService.class);


    public List<Person> getAll() {
        logger.debug("Retrieving all persons");
        List<Person> person = personRepository.findAll();
        return person;
    }

    public void add(Person person) {
        logger.debug("Adding new person");
        personRepository.save(person);
    }
}
```

CreditCardService ::

```
package com.example.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.model.CreditCard;
import com.example.repository.CreditCardRepository;
import com.example.repository.PersonRepository;

@Service
public class CreditCardService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreditCardService.class);

    @Autowired
    CreditCardRepository creditCardRepository;

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @Transactional
    public void add(CreditCard creditCard) {
        logger.debug("Adding new credit card");
//      String number = creditCard.getNumber();
//      String type = creditCard.getType();
//      Integer id = creditCard.getPerson().getId();
        creditCardRepository.save(creditCard);
        //creditCardRepository.insertData(number,type,id);
    }

    public List<CreditCard> getAll(Integer id) {
        List<CreditCard> credit = creditCardRepository.getAll(id);
        return credit;
    }

    public List<CreditCard> get(Integer id) {
        List<CreditCard> credit = creditCardRepository.get(id);
        return credit;
    }

    public void addAll(List<CreditCard> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.debug("Adding new credit card With Old List");
        creditCardRepository.saveAll(list);
    }

}
```

CreditCardRepositry ::

```
package com.example.repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.example.model.CreditCard;

public interface CreditCardRepository extends JpaRepository<CreditCard,Integer>{

    @Query("SELECT v FROM Person u INNER JOIN  u.creditCard v  WHERE u.id = ?1")
     List<CreditCard>  getAll(Integer id);

//  @Query("insert into CreditCard  (number,type,person.id) VALUES (?1,?2,?3)")
//  void insertData(String number, String type, Integer id);

    @Query("SELECT c FROM CreditCard c WHERE c.person.id = ?1")
    List<CreditCard> get(Integer id);

}
```

I'm using jsp pages here to add person as well as creditcard.

To show Person and its related creditcard.

List.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Person Details</title>
</head>
<body>

        <h1>Person Credit Card Details</h1>
        <h2>
            <a href="add">Add New Person</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="PersonList">List All Person</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <!--  <a href="benefits/beneficiary"></a> -->

        </h2>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>PersonID</th>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>Money</th>
                <th>CC Type</th>
                <th>CC Number</th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
            </tr>
         <c:forEach var="person" items="${persons}">
                <c:if test = "${!empty person.creditCard}">
                    <c:forEach items="${person.creditCard}" var = "creditCards">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${person.id}</td>
                            <td>${person.firstName}</td>
                            <td>${person.lastName}</td>
                            <td>${person.money}</td>
                            <td>${creditCards.type}</td>
                            <td>${creditCards.number}</td>
                            <!-- <c:url var="addcc" value="/main/creditcard/add?id=${person.id}" />
                            <td><a href = "${addcc}">Add Credit Card</a></td> -->
                             <td><a href="/main/creditcard/add/<c:out value='${person.id}' />">Add Credit Card</a></td> 

                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty person.creditCard}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${person.id}</td>
                        <td>${person.firstName}</td>
                        <td>${person.lastName}</td>
                        <td>${person.money}</td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                        <td> <a href="/main/creditcard/add/<c:out value='${person.id}' />">Add Credit Card</a></td>
                        <!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; --> 
                        <!-- <td><a href="/delete/<c:out value='${employee.employeeId}' />">Delete</a> </td>  -->
                        <!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -->
                        <!-- <td> <a href="benefits/show/<c:out value='${employee.employeeId}' />">Benefits</a> </td>   -->
                    </tr>
                </c:if>         
        </c:forEach>                     
        </table>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

AddPerson.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
      <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="personEntry" method="post">
            <table style="with: 50%">
                <tr>
                    <td>FirstName</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" /></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>LastName</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Money</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="money" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
</body>

</html>
```

AddCreditCard.jsp ::

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
      <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:url var="addCcUrl" value="/main/creditcard/addCard?id=${personId}" />
<form:form action="${addCcUrl}" method="post" modelAttribute = "creditCardAttribute">
            <table style="with: 50%">
                <tr>
                    <td>PersonId</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="${personId}" name = "personId" readonly/>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Card Type</td>
                    <td><form:input path="type" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number</td>
                    <td><form:input path="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </form:form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove

```
(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

from  `CreditCard` Class?
It's like you are telling hibernate to persist a person every time you persist a new credit card

Let just the annotation

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="person_id", nullable=false)
 private Person person;
```

Can you try to add `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` to `Person` class instead?
Juste like that

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person"cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
     private List<CreditCard> creditCard;
```

try this code for adding a new credit card

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCard", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView postAdd(@RequestParam("personId") Integer personId,@ModelAttribute("creditCardAttribute") CreditCard creditCard,BindingResult binding) { @ModelAttribute("creditCard") CreditCard creditCard

        Person p = personRepository.findById(personId).get();

        creditCard.setPerson(p);

        creditCardRepository.save(creditCard);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/PersonList");
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it but then also it **updating the existing credit card instead of adding new one.**

Comment: @mr-vaibhav please take a look at my modified answer